# Can't get Python GCP Cloud Run gRPC service to respond

Tags: docker, grpc, google-cloud-run, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I am developing a chat app that has three main components (so far). I shall described the "architecture" of the working local development environment:

- a client in SolidJS running in vite, using `nice-grpc-web` (a little TypeScript gRPC-web library)
- an Envoy proxy running in a Docker container
- a Python gRPC server that streams responses from Haystack's `PromptNode`, running directly on my machine but also tested and happy to run in a Docker container

This is all working fine locally

With a view to moving it into the cloud, I deployed the Python app in a Docker container as a Cloud Run service on GCP.

Now, this service is running happily and is looging that it is happy and is responding to health checks. So I think that is all good.

However, reconfiguring my Envoy proxy to point to this service, rather than my local Python gRPC server, causes the whole thing to break. I get messages from Envoy telling me that the endpoints can't be reached:

> ClientError: /ChatBot/AskQuestion UNAVAILABLE: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

So it is either the Envoy config that is making it unhappy, or the Cloud Run service that is making it unhappy. I have done lots of reading around both, but can't work it out.

Things that I imagine might be causing it:

- the protocol is different. Now it is running over https, might I need to add more config to Envoy to support this?
- I had to override the port on Cloud Run (standard is 8080, I am using 50051). Although it is responding on this port to the health checks from GCP, is there some further config I need to do?
- perhaps a CORS issue? But I would expect the response to reflect that
- although I have checked to make sure it is available to the internet and not just internally, could this be causing an issue?

The only even vaguely helpful article I have come across is [this one](https://www.ackee.agency/blog/how-to-setup-a-grpc-web-backend-on-google-cloud-run-with-envoy-proxy), but that doesn't work either.

Here is my `envoy.yaml`, actual service name elided:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              codec_type: auto
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              route_config:
                name: local_route
                virtual_hosts:
                  - name: local_service
                    domains: ["*"]
                    routes:
                      - match: { prefix: "/" }
                        route:
                          cluster: chat_service
                          timeout: 0s
                          max_stream_duration:
                            grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                    cors:
                      allow_origin_string_match:
                        - prefix: "*"
                      allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                      allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                      max_age: "1728000"
                      expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
              http_filters:
                - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: chat_service
      type: logical_dns
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      connect_timeout: 20s
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      typed_extension_protocol_options:
        envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
          explicit_http_config:
            http2_protocol_options: { }
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: myapp.a.run.app
                    port_value: 50051
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM envoyproxy/envoy:v1.26.1

COPY envoy.yaml /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml

EXPOSE 9901
EXPOSE 50051
EXPOSE 50052
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/envoy" ]
CMD [ "-c /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml", "-l trace", "--log-path /tmp/envoy_info.log" ]
```

Suggestions please!

Comment: What are ports 8080, 9901, and 50051? Cloud Run only supports one listening TCP port.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to remove those from the docker file, they are unused. In any case, that’s the Envoy file, which is running locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your envoy proxy needs to connect to your Cloud Run URL on port 443. There's a few layers of proxies in between your app and the Internet, so the port your application runs on isn't exposed publicly.

Comment: Turns out, having deployed the Envoy proxy to Cloud Run, it is all working now; although I had changed the port to 443. Not sure how that ends up being mapped to 8080, on which the app is actually running , but I don't need to understand that right now!

Comment: It's because your application is actually envoy -> Google Front End -> application container. The Google Front End does SSL termination and load balancing and things like that, and it listens on port 443 and forwards requests to your application port in your container after doing its things.